# Superfluous un-simplifiable condition returned by Reduce

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

No real "problem" here, just wondering why this is happening and how one might force Mathematica to simplify this. Consider:

```
Reduce[(-1)^n == 1, n \[Element] Reals]

(* Out: (C[1] \[Element] Integers && n == 2 C[1]) || n == 0 *)
```

Note the weird "`... || n == 0`" even though that's a special case of the left disjunct, with `C[1] -> 0`. Applying `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` don't get rid of the superfluous `n == 0` condition. (Including the assumption `0 \[Element] Integers` doesn't help either; it immediately evaluates to `True`.)

Another strange thing is that

```
Reduce[(-1)^n == 1, n \[Element] Integers]
```

doesn't include the superfluous condition! It just returns `(C[1] \[Element] Integers && n == 2 C[1])`.

What's causing this, and is there a general "lack of ability to unify special cases" in `Simplify` and the like that it's worth watching out for? And why does using `Integers` instead of `Reals` change the behavior?

Comment: I suspect there’s a discrete `Integers` code and an analytic `Reals` code, each called separately in the first case, and the analytic code returns `0`.

Comment: OTOH, if you apply `ExpToTrig` to `(-1)^n` in the first example, the extraneous `n == 0` goes away.

Comment: `Simplify[Reduce[(-1)^n == 1, n \[Element] Reals], 
 Assumptions -> n != 0]`  gives `Element[n/2, Integers]` in MMA 12.1